# MySQL concat elements into unique set from serialized arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, serialization

If I have a mysql call which returns a collection of serialized arrays that looks like the following

```
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"381";i:1;s:3:"376";}
a:3:{i:0;s:3:"381";i:1;s:3:"376";i:2;s:3:"377";}
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"376";i:1;s:3:"344";}
```

Is it possible to instead get it to return one serialized array with the set of unique strings?

Something like

```
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"376";i:1;s:3:"381";i:1;s:3:"377";i:1;s:3:"344";}
```

The current call for reference is

```
select distinct b.meta_value
from wp_posts join wp_postmeta b on b.post_id = ID
where post_type = "customType" and b.meta_key = "authors" and b.meta_value != ""
```

Comment: You're not going to have much luck working directly with serialized PHP strings in MySQL - you'll need to use PHP for this.

Comment: The only way to do this in MySQL is with a stored procedure that parses the strings, creates a temporary table to hold the values, uses that to get the unique values, then constructs a new serialized string from that. Crazy to try to do this in MySQL.

Comment: I'm newer to SQL and don't have a good grasp on the built-in functions yet. Good to know this goes beyond what's meant to be done in sql. Thanks!